# Paraview Rendering - RenderWindow not responding?

Tags: python, windows, paraview

Trying to get a basic paraview script running on my windows 7 PC. Code is:

```
from paraview.simple import *
Cone()
Show()
Render()
```

The Render window opens but it is unresponsive. If I check task manager then is is listed as 'Not Responding' Sometimes the Cone appears as it should but the window is still unresponsive and I have to kill the window.

I have had the same setup render things with VTK with better success, so not sure what about paraview may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `pvpython`/`pvbatch` render window is not designed to be interactive. It is intended for batch scripting and hence you cannot manually interact with it. There are plans to add support for interaction in future.

Comment: Is there a method for closing it properly from the pvpython shell? I tried Delete(GetRenderView()) but I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Views'